# Editing ObservableDictionary via DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

I binded my ObservableDictionary to a DataGrid.ItemSource .
My problem is when i try to edit a value via the datagrid.
I get the exception "Edititem is not allowed for this view".
I've tried different solutions - such as binding the ObservableDictionary.Values.ToList to the datagrid - which makes it possible to edit items but the original value collection is no longer binded.

So, how do I bind ObservableDictionary to a DataGrid and i still keep it editable.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, do you use autogeneratecolumns? The ObservableDictionary is the one from codeplex? Some code examples would help :).

Answer (score 1):

While trying to do basically the same thing recently, I've came upon [ObservableKeyedCollection](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2010/01/12/make-keyedcollectionlttkey-titemgt-to-work-properly-with-wpf-data-binding.aspx). It requires the key to be stored within the item class (which, by the way, is the source of trouble with `ObservableDictionary` - it uses `KeyValuePair<>` struct for enumeration, and that struct isn't editable), but works together with DataGrid, allowing it to edit the items.

Answer (score -1):

You may find the following helpful:

> Working with editing commands
>   Default commands have been added to the DataGrid to support editing.  These commands and their default input bindings are:

- ·         BeginEditCommand (F2) ·
- CancelEditCommand (Esc) ·
- CommitEditCommand (Enter) ·
- DeleteCommand (Delete)

The whole blog post is here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx